# Good book on large deviations theory

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, large-deviation-theory

I am interested in reading about large deviations theory. Can anybody please suggest me any good book regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I think one of the classics, which I just started reading is Zeitouni and Dembo's [Large Deviations Techniques and Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642033105). So far, it seems to be well written and Zeitouni is an expert in the field.

Comment: Indeed a classic, and excellent. An alternative, possibly more accessible and definitely shorter, is Frank den Hollander's [Large deviations](https://www.amazon.com/Large-Deviations-Fields-Institute-Monographs/dp/0821844350).